# Prove: $3^{100}k+3^{99}+\sum_{i=0}^{98} \left(3^i\cdot 2^{\sum_{j=i+2}^{100}n_j}\right)=2^{\sum_{i=1}^{100}n_i+m}?$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $\left\{n_1,n_2,n_3, \ldots,n_{98},n_{99},n_{100}\right\}\subset\mathbb{N}$ be given.

Prove that there are always $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$3^{100}k+3^{99}+\sum_{i=0}^{98} \left(3^i×2^{\sum_{j=i+2}^{100}n_j}\right)=2^{m+\sum_{i=1}^{100}n_i}$$

I want to solve this question. But the question is very difficult for me. I am thankful for any help.

Comment: where did you find this problem?

Comment: The teacher gave it to me...

Comment: How should we read $\sum_{i=1}^{100}n_i+m?$ $\sum_{i=1}^{100}(n_i+m)$ or $(\sum_{i=1}^{100}n_i)+m$

Comment: Second is true . @miracle173

Comment: @miracle173 $(\sum_{i=1}^{100}n_i)+m$

Comment: I'm not sure this is algebraic number theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we set 
$$ M=3^{100}$$
$$A=3^{99}+\sum_{i=0}^{98} \left(3^i\cdot 2^{\sum_{j=i+2}^{100}n_j}\right)$$
$$B=2^{\sum_{i=1}^{100}n_i}$$
we have
$$\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}: \; \exists m\in \mathbb{Z}: \; 3^{100}k+3^{99}+\sum_{i=0}^{98} \left(3^i\cdot 2^{\sum_{j=i+2}^{100}n_j}\right)=2^{\sum_{i=1}^{100}n_i+m}\\
\iff\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}: \; \exists m\in \mathbb{Z}: \; M\cdot k + A = B\cdot 2^m \\
\iff\exists m\in \mathbb{Z}: \; A \equiv B\cdot 2^m \pmod M \\
\iff\exists m\in \mathbb{Z}: \; A \cdot B^{-1}\equiv  2^m \pmod M$$

$B^{-1}\pmod M$ exists because $\gcd(B,3)=1$.

We need the following lemma:

**Lemma:**

If $k \in \mathbb{N}, k \ge 2$ then

$$2^{2\cdot 3^{k-2}} = 3^{k-1}+1 + u_k\cdot  3^k $$
$$2^{3^{k-1}} = 3^{k}-1 + v_k\cdot  3^k $$

where $u_k$ and $v_k$ in $\mathbb{Z}.$

**Proof:**

This will be proved by induction.

- The statment is true for $k=2$ because

$$2^{2\cdot 3^{2-2}} = 4= 3^{2-1}+1 + 0 \cdot 3^2 $$
$$2^{3^{2-1}} = 3^{2}-1 + 0\cdot  3^k $$

- if the statement is true for a $k\ge 2$ than we can conclude that

$$2^{2\cdot 3^{k-1}} \\
=(2^{2\cdot 3^{k-2}})^3 \\
= (3^{k-1}+1 + u_k\cdot  3^k)^3\\
=3^k+1+(3^{2 k-1}\cdot u_k ^3
+3^{2 k-1}\cdot u_k ^2+3^k\cdot u_k ^2\\
+3^{2 k-2}\cdot u_k +2\cdot 3^{k-1}\cdot u_k +u_k +3^{2 k-4}+3^{k-2})\cdot 3^{k+1}
\\=3^k+1+u_{k+1}\cdot 3^{k+1}$$
and
$$2^{3^{k}}=\\
(2^{3^{k-1}})^3=\\
(3^k-1+v_k\cdot 3^k)^3\\
=3^{k+1}-1+(3^{2 k-1}\cdot v_k ^3+3^{2 k}\cdot v_k ^2-3^k\cdot v_k ^2\\
+3^{2 k}\cdot v_k -2\cdot 3^k\cdot v_k +v_k +3^{2 k-1}-3^k)\cdot 3^{k+1}\\
=3^{k+1}-1+v_{k+1}\cdot 3^{k+1}
$$
Therefore the statement is true for $k+1$

$\blacksquare$

We have $2^{2\cdot 3^{98}}\equiv 2^{\varphi(3^{99})}\equiv 1\pmod M.$ From the lemma follows  that $2^{3^{98}} \equiv 3^{98}+1 \not\equiv 1\pmod M$ and $2^{2\cdot 3^{97}} \equiv 3^{99}-1\not\equiv 1\pmod M$ and so $2$ is a *primitive root* $\pmod M$. So every element that is relative prime to $3$ can be generated as power of $2$. But
$$A\equiv 2^{\sum_{j=2}^{100} n_j} \in \{-1,1\}\pmod M$$
So $\gcd(A,3)=1.$ Therefore the statement is true.

Comment: I read. +1. Thanks for help

Comment: Is english your first language?

Comment: No, your  answer is perfect ( and your reputation is very high). I accepted..I want to ask a new question on MSE. But  I can not translate English. Is there a way you know?

Comment: Turkish ...I tried Google, Yandex, Microsoft translate..but MSE downvoted the question..

Comment: which question?

Comment: I deleted..MSE said that question is unclear and downvoted :(